# No org-babel-execute function for calc?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In `org-mode`:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC calc :var x=5 :var y=2
2+a*x**y
#+END_SRC
```

returns

```
No org-babel-execute function for calc!
```

How do I enable `calc` for `org-babel-execute`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in org [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Languages.html#Languages):

> By default, only 'emacs-lisp' is enabled for evaluation.  To enable
>   or disable other languages, customize the 'org-babel-load-languages'
>   variable either through the Emacs customization interface, or by adding
>   code to the init file as shown next:
>
> In this example, evaluation is disabled for 'emacs-lisp', and enabled
>   for `R'.
>
> ```
> (org-babel-do-load-languages
>   'org-babel-load-languages
>   '((emacs-lisp . nil)
>     (R . t)))
> ```

So here you could do the following:

```el
(org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
      '((calc . t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to JeanPierre's answer, you can run `M-x customize-variable` with `org-babel-load-languages` to modify the list from Emacs.