# org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for R!

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, r

In org-mode, attempting to execute the following block...

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R
1+2
#+END_SRC
```

...gives the error message `org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for R!`. I have followed the instructions in https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html. My `.emacs` contains:

```
(require 'ess-site)
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((R . t)))
```

Here's the content of my `Messages` buffer.

```
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/00debian.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for R!
```

I have looked at the answers to [No org-babel-execute function for calc?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/33103/19311) and ["no org-babel-execute function for c" and "no-org-babel-execute function for c++"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17673/19311) but they did not solve my problem.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I'm on Debian and have installed `ess`.

EDIT: I did exit emacs and restart it. And just to make sure that the current version of `.emacs` is being picked up, I made a tiny change to it, which took effect as expected.

EDIT: I'm using GNU Emacs 25.2.2.

EDIT: Here's my entire .emacs file, in case it helps. I've made a few changes to it while experimenting with this problem. I added Haskell to the list of languages to see if the problem was specific to R, but I'm getting the "No org-babel-execute function for haskell!" message when I try to execute a Haskell block.

```
;; No startup screen
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)

;; No toolbar
(tool-bar-mode -1)

;; Open my emacs "cheat sheet"
(defun wombat-emacs-help ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file "~/néal/eolas/emacs.txt"))

;; CUA
(cua-mode t)

;; Use a bar for the cursor
(set-default 'cursor-type 'box)
;; box, hollow, bar, or hbar

;; Set location for custom scripts.
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs.d")

;; My custom key bindings
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") (quote save-buffer))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-r") (quote query-replace))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") (quote isearch-forward))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-forward)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-repeat-forward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-f") (quote isearch-backward))
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-S-f") 'isearch-repeat-backward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-#") (quote comment-dwim))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") (quote mark-whole-buffer))
;; (global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") (quote browse-apropos-url-on-region))
;; (global-set-key (kbd "C-SPC") (quote hippie-expand))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-?") (quote wombat-emacs-help))
(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-switchb)

;; open with single window
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'delete-other-windows)

;; Show column-number in the mode line
(column-number-mode 1)

;; Highlight current line
(global-hl-line-mode)

;; Margin (fill column)
(setq-default fill-column 72)

;; Margin indicator
(require 'fill-column-indicator)
(setq fci-rule-width 1)
(setq fci-rule-color "lightblue")
(add-hook 'awk-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
(add-hook 'erlang-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
(add-hook 'shell-script-mode-hook 'fci-mode)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'fci-mode)

;; (setq amys-launch-directory default-directory)
;; (autoload 'whe "whe" "Wombat haskell stuff" t nil)

;; Longer "Buffers" menu
(setq buffers-menu-max-size 50)

;; Highlight matching parentheses
(show-paren-mode)

;; Haskell unicode source candy
(setq haskell-font-lock-symbols t)

;; ;; Haskell indentation
;; (add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'haskell-indentation-mode)

;; Use Hasktags
(let ((my-stack-path (expand-file-name "~/.local/bin")))
  (setenv "PATH" (concat my-stack-path path-separator (getenv "PATH")))
  (add-to-list 'exec-path my-stack-path))
(custom-set-variables '(haskell-tags-on-save t)

;; Stylish Haskell
(custom-set-variables
 '(haskell-stylish-on-save t))

;; R
;; (require 'org)
;; (require 'org-install)
;; (require 'ess-site)
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '(
   (R . t)
   (dot . t)
   (haskell . t)
   (python . t)
   (sh . t)
   ))

;; Repos
(require 'package) ;; This is built-in
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
;; (package-refresh-contents)

;; Find out the major mode associated with a buffer.
(defun buffer-mode (&optional buffer-or-name)
  "Returns the major mode associated with a buffer.
If buffer-or-name is nil return current buffer's mode."
  (buffer-local-value 'major-mode
   (if buffer-or-name (get-buffer buffer-or-name) (current-buffer))))

;;
;; Remove trailing whitespace
;;
(defun remove-trailing-whitespace ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "[ \t]+$" nil t)
      (replace-match "" nil nil)))
  nil)
(defun add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook ()
  (add-hook 'local-write-file-hooks 'remove-trailing-whitespace))

(add-hook 'awk-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
(add-hook 'erlang-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
(add-hook 'shell-script-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'add-remove-trailing-whitespace-hook)
```

EDIT: Just to rule out the obvious, I *do* have `R` and `Haskell` installed on my system.

Comment: I assume you've re-evaluated your `.emacs` file?  I just added the `org-babel-do-load-languages` section to mine, evaluated it, and do not get the `No org-babel-execute function for R` error.  I get a different error because R is not installed on my system, which is expected.

Comment: It would also be good to know what version of Emacs you are using.

Comment: @GrantShangreaux I added the answers to the end of my post.

Comment: does this happen only with R or also with other languages? Try an elisp code block, i.e. `#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(+ 1 1)
#+END_SRC`

Comment: @bombadil The elisp code block *will* execute, but the Haskell code block I tried won't.

Comment: @bombadil I've added an "sh" (shell) code block, and it won't execute either. (In the full listing of my `.emacs` file that I added to my post, you can see that I added entries for Haskell and sh.)

Comment: can you verify, that the languages are loaded correctly with `M-x describe-variable <RET> org-babel-load-languages`.

Comment: I was going to suggest also trying to evaluate just the `(org-babel-do-load-languages ...)` function call while Emacs is running.  If you evaluate it and it works, it might just be an issue with the order things are set up in your config.

Comment: @GrantShangreaux, I tried that and you were right. Moving the `(org-babel-do-load-languages...` stuff earlier in my .emacs solved the problem. If you want to turn that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @bombadil, your suggestions were also valuable. If you want to turn them into an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the behavior with your `.emacs` file.  I found one syntax error that I thought might be the issue:

```
(custom-set-variables '(haskell-tags-on-save t)
```

that line is missing a closing paren.  however, adding it did not solve the problem.  I had to move the `org-babel-do-load-languages` call above the `fill-column-indicator` section in order for babel to work properly.

I eventually figured out why after commenting out these two lines:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'delete-other-windows)
```

Loading `.emacs` was failing because there was no such package as `fill-column-indicator` on my system. I couldn't find it anywhere in the repositories, but assuming you have it installed, loading the file would still fail at that missing paren on the line I mentioned before.  I'm guessing nothing after that point in your file is evaluated properly.

I found a third error, which is the org babel language `sh` has been renamed to `shell` so you'll also need to change that line from `(sh .t)` to `(shell . t)`.  I hope this helps!

p.s. there are some linting functions for emacs-lisp which might help catch errors like missing parens, `elint-current-buffer`, and `elint-file` specifically.